# What am I missing that keeps giving call to member function error?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a simple query to process search results. I will make it PDO safe later, but for now, I keep getting a Call to a member function execute() on a non-object error, BUT I can't see anything below that is causing this. The error is at the line $results->execute();

The PDO object/connection works fine and my code works on every other page but this one. What on Earth am I missing? Some syntax error somehow?

```
$last = $_GET['last'];
$author = $_GET['author'];

$results = $dbh->prepare("select
wp_users.ID AS user_id,
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
FROM wp_users
WHERE wp_users.display_name = $author; ");
$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but does it replace $author with a quoted version, or are you required to put the quotes around it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

It is returning false, due to invalid sql most likely.  To check the actual error, you can do:

```
if (!$results) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Most likely, the variable you are using is not quoted, which is why you should really just use named parameters to begin with, since it's not really any more difficult:

```
 $results = $dbh->prepare("select wp_users.ID AS user_id, 
                           wp_users.ID, 
                           wp_users.display_name,
                           FROM wp_users
                           WHERE wp_users.display_name = :author");

 $results->execute([':author' => $author]);
```

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't like the [ or =>. Got errors for both of those. Tried, but I can't use the (!$results test because I keep getting the same Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object error and nothing else on the page.

Comment: I just restructured everything and got it to go. Not worths sharing solution since the approach has nothing to do with this post.